# C++ Windows cant bind the socket

Tags: c++, sockets

i am using NO-IP to point my public adress also i forward the port 8844 but still my server doesnt work. when i try " 127.0.0.1 " instead host it works,i couldnt find where is the mistake..

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShow)
{
    WORD sockVer;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int retVal;

    sockVer = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    WSAStartup(sockVer, &wsaData);

    /// Creating socket
    SOCKET servSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (servSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to create socket()", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);
        WSACleanup();
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    /// Filling in sockaddr_in struct 

    struct hostent* host = gethostbyname("myhostadress");

    SOCKADDR_IN sin;
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(8844);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host->h_addr);




    retVal = bind(servSock, (LPSOCKADDR)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    if (retVal == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to bind", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);

        WSACleanup();
        return WSAGetLastError();
    }
```

Comment: And the error number was? NB the error number *before* you call `WSACleanup()`. Posting a question without an error message or number here is just a complete waste of time.

Comment: grab `WSAGetLastError()` before calling `WSACleanup` and print it out. Then [look up the error code here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what happened.

Comment: Then lookup the error code at **MSDN** to see what happened. @user4581301

Comment: How can i print easiliy, the messagebox is not compaitble...

Comment: @elliot std::to_string(WSAGetLastError()) will give you std::string which can be shown in message box

Comment: @marcinj but messagebox is not string type :/ its supports char...

Comment: `std::string` is a mighty beast. [It even has a function to return a pointer to a char array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

Comment: Got back too late to make that fix, @EJP . Thanks for recommending it though.

Comment: While you're fixing your code are sure to fix this everywhere, e.g. above where you create the socket, and later when you connect, listen, accept, send, receive, ...

Comment: i am getting " cannot assign requsted adress' error ( 10049 ) how can i fix it ? why it is not assigng to mine public ip ?

Comment: Ahhh... Based on that, and kicking myself a bit, print out `host->h_addr`. I don't think you'll like what you see and I'm damn sure `inet_addr` isn't able to parse it.

Comment: If this is going to be a listening socket you should bind it to INADDR_ANY, not a specific host address.

Comment: @EJP: there is nothing wrong with binding a listening socket to a specific address. In a multi-homed machine, you might not want to listen on all adapters.  Or maybe a protocol restriction requires accepting connections on a specific adapter only.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Of course, but not for beginners. The problem here is clearly that he isn't binding to a valid IP address. Walk before you run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `gethostbyname()` (without error checking) to get your public IP (there are other ways to get that IP without using a DNS lookup).  If your server is behind a NAT/router (as is implied by your comment that you have to forward the port to your server), then you are binding to the wrong IP.  You can only bind to an IP that belongs to a network adapter that is local to the server machine.  In a NAT environment, that means binding to a private LAN IP that has been assigned to the server, not to the NAT's public WAN IP.  The NAT will forward connections from its public WAN IP to the server's private LAN IP, and then the server can accept connections on its private LAN IP.  This also allows the server to accept connections from clients running on other machines with the same LAN.

Also, `inet_addr()` expects an IP address in dotted string format, but `gethostbyname()` returns IP addresses in binary format instead.  When the `hostent::h_addrtype` field is `AF_INET` (which `gethostbyname()` is not guaranteed to return), the `hostent::h_addr_list` field contains pointers to `in_addr` structs, which you can then assign as-is to the `sin.sin_addr` field.

It would be easier to just bind to `INADDR_ANY` so the server can accept connections on *any* local IP universally, instead of binding to any specific IP.

Try this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShow)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int retVal;

    retVal = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (retVal != 0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to initialize WinSock", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    /// Creating socket
    SOCKET servSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (servSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to create socket", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    /// Filling in sockaddr_in struct 

    SOCKADDR_IN sin = {0};
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(8844);
    //sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.16.0.1"); // whatever your LAN IP is
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    retVal = bind(servSock, (LPSOCKADDR)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    if (retVal == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        retVal = WSAGetLastError();
        MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to bind socket", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);
        closesocket(servSock);
        WSACleanup();
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    retVal = listen(servSock, ...);
    if (retVal == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        retVal = WSAGetLastError();
        MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to listen on socket", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);
        closesocket(servSock);
        WSACleanup();
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    ...

    closesocket(servSock);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`getaddrinfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx) instead and let it tell you which IP(s) to bind to:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShow)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int retVal;

    retVal = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (retVal != 0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to initialize WinSock", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    addrinfo hints = {0};
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    addrinfo *addrs
    retVal = getaddrinfo(NULL, "8844", &hints, &addrs);
    if (retVal != 0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to get addr info", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);
        WSACleanup();
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    std::vector<SOCKET> servSocks;

    /// Creating sockets
    for(addrinfo *addr = addrs; addr != NULL; addr = addr->ai_next)
    { 
        SOCKET servSock = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
        if (servSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
            continue;

        retVal = bind(servSock, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen);
        if (retVal == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(servSock);
            continue;
        }

        retVal = listen(servSock, ...);
        if (retVal == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(servSock);
            continue;
        }

        servSocks.push_back(servSock);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(addrs);

    if (servSocks.empty())
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to prepare listening socket(s)", "SOCKET ERROR", MB_OK);
        WSACleanup();
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    ...

    std::for_each(servSocks.begin(), servSocks.end(), &::closesocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Either way, your NO-IP service simply maps a static hostname to your NAT's current public IP, nothing more.  When a client wants to connect to the hostname, it first resolves the hostname to its current IP, and then connects to that IP.  It is connecting to your NAT router, not to your server directly.  The router will forward the client to the private LAN IP that your server is bound to, where the server can then accept the connection.  So make sure your router's port forwarding rules are configured correctly.  If that is not working correctly, you should ask on [ServerFault.com](http://serverfault.com), as that is a networking issue, not a coding issue.

Comment: i am getting this error at servSocks.push_back(servSocks) : http://i.hizliresim.com/njLg2V.jpg

Comment: A typo on my part. I have corrected it. `(servSocks)` should be `(servSock)` instead.

Comment: Also how can i add my ip as host name to this, sorry my brain is working so slow now i didint sleep for 27+ hour

Comment: @Elliot if i understand you correctly, then nothing changes. You simply register a hosthame that resolves to an IP address that can reach your server, either directly or through a router. There are plenty of 3rd party DNS services available for that purpose, like DynDNS, etc. If that is not what you mean, then please clarify your question.

Comment: i couldnt figure out how to add the ip adress, cause it is different way from what i did, can you help me plase

Comment: @Elliot I still do not understand what you are asking. Please clarify your question. What EXACTLY are you having trouble with?

Comment: sorry for my really basic questions but i coudlnt figure out where-how will i  add the ip adress...

Comment: @Elliot add the IP address to what? Your question is not basic, it's vague.

Comment: I want the servers IP adress be a hostname. i mean i am using NO-IP to point my public unstatic ip adress..

Comment: @Elliot I ready addressed that in a comment 2 days ago. You are already using a DNS service that links your public dynamic IP to a static hostname. If your server is connected *directly* to your Internet connection, that is all you need. But if your server is behind a router then you need to configure the router's port forwarding rules so public Internet clients are forwarded to your server. That is beyond the scope of StackOverflow, check your router's settings, or ask on http://serverfault.com

Comment: I think there is a misunderstood :)  i am writing a server for windows rightnow. i already forwarded my port from router. and at the above code as is see there is nothing to associate my host. dont i need that ?

Comment: @Elliot: No, you don't. That is strictly related to network routing, it has nothing to do with coding. Your server code can only bind to a *local* IP on the same machine. Your router needs to route outside clients from the public IP to the server IP. Clients never see the server IP directly, and the server never sees the public IP directly. The hostname is just a convenient way for outside clients to discover your current public IP. The router handles the rest. Again, not a coding issue for StackOverflow. Network administration belongs on ServerFault instead.

Comment: sorry i had some problems with my internet i couldnt response. then how will i know the servers ip to connect ? i mean client is not static ip, neither server..

Comment: @Elliot your NO-IP service handles that for you. It gives you a static hostname and keeps it updated with your latest public IP whenever it changes. When a client wants to connect, it uses DNS to lookup the hostname's current IP, then connects to it. That IP belongs to your router, which forwards the connect to the server IP where your software is listening. Now please, get yourself a good book on networking and do some research, you keep asking the same questions and we're just going around in circles.